# Understanding the Dirac Spinor under Lorentz Transformation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, dirac-equation

Recently I have been studying SR and QFT (in the beginnings). Initially it was a bit hard for me to understand, conceptually the Lorentz transformations. I will give a brief description of my current understanding of the Lorentz Transformation and I will try to do the same for when we consider the Dirac-Spinor, the solution to the Dirac equation. This is where I am not sure and I'd like feedback.

The setup is as follows:

There's an event taking place. We consider two intertial reference frame, the rest frame of the event (F) and another one, which relative to it (rest frame of the event) moves in an arbitrary direction (F'). Each observer observes the event directly and therefore each registers a four position vector for the event, namely (t,x,y,z) for F and (t',x',y',z'). Now, for simplicity assuming that the event is spacelike, they both can find the spacetime interval, which will turn out to be the spatial distance, namely L for F and L' for F'.
This is where the LTs come into play. If either of them want to "experience" what the other experiences, they would use the LT. For example, if the observer in F' uses the LTs he will gain a new set of (t',x',y',z') which will be different than what he got when he observed it himself. By using these newly acquired coordinates in the spacetime interval, he will calculate the same spatial distance that the observer in F finds. The other way around is also similar, when F uses inverse LT to "experience" or witness how the observer in F' sees/registers/records the events. I believe my understanding for this is correct.

Now, let's consider the Dirac equation and it's solution $\psi$. Each observer can consider this equation and find the solution to it.

For the observer in F:

$(i\hbar\gamma^\mu \partial_\mu -mc)\psi(x^\mu)=0$

For the observer in F':

$(i\hbar\gamma^\mu \partial^{'}_\mu -mc)\psi'(x^{'\mu})=0$.

Now, one can start with the D.E from F and arrive at an equation in F' of the form:

$$[i\hbar S(\Lambda)\gamma^\mu S^{-1}(\Lambda)\Lambda^\nu_\mu\partial^{'}_\mu -mc]\psi'(x^{'\mu})=0$$

where $\psi(x^\mu)=S^{-1}(\Lambda)\psi'(x'^\mu)$.

Now I am trying to understand the point of using LT to the DE. I understand that one reason why we consider the LT to this equation, is to see if it is Lorentz covariant, that way, if it is, than it is a valid equation in the relativistic framework. But when it comes to the reason why would any of the observers in F or F' use LT on the DE, that I don't understand.
If I have to guess, is it maybe because each observer wants to know how the solution looks like for the other? If so, than who uses which transformation? What I mean by that, I will describe it better by considering a scenario:

The observer in F (rest frame of some arbitrary event(s)) considers the D.E and solves it by finding the Dirac-spinor $\psi(x^\mu)$. Now, will the observer in F be the one two calculate this equation:

$$[i\hbar S(\Lambda)\gamma^\mu S^{-1}(\Lambda)\Lambda^\nu_\mu\partial^{'}_\mu -mc]\psi'(x^{'\mu})=0$$

If yes, then by solving it, he will find the solution as calculated by the observer in F'. But if that's the case, where the observer in F transforms the D.E in the above expression and tries find it's solution, isn't he, the observer in F, taking the long road? Can't he simply consider that: $\psi'(x'^\mu)=S(\Lambda)\psi(x^\mu)$? And the same goes for the observer in F'. can't he do $\psi(x^\mu)=S^{-1}(\Lambda)\psi'(x'^\mu)$ and find the solution to the DE as solved by the observer in F. If what I say is doable, then what is the point of  an observer in one of the frames using LT to transform the Dirac Equation of his frame, to that of the other observer?